# Graph calls for installing app on Teams returns 409 (Conflict)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

My graph calls have suddenly started to return 409 (Conflict) when trying install an app for a Team - any ideas on why?

The app I'm trying to install is the Dynamics 365 app with the teamsAppId: cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41

The call I use (POST):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[my](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%5Bmy) team id]/installedApps

the body:

```
{
  "teamsApp odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41"
}
```

The reponse:

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": "Conflict",
 "message": "AppEntitlement id: 'cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41' already exists in TeamId:  '19:e2pHF8IE87LgVTlA_4zDD5LblLqViGo7GcdtcsW9hOw1@thread.tacv2' ",
 "innerError": {
 "message": "AppEntitlement id: 'cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41' already exists in TeamId:   '19:e2pHF8IE87LgVTlA_4zDD5LblLqViGo7GcdtcsW9hOw1@thread.tacv2' ",
 "code": "Conflict",
 "innerError": {},
 "date": "2022-03-28T18:13:36",
 "request-id": "424e8c44-ab49-4706-9dc0-1af3ecea6145",
 "client-request-id": "248ad040-ab62-5190-26a8-c2da6127716c"
}
}
```

Troubleshooting:

To confirm the app is not installed and If I run a call to check if the app is installed using (GET):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[my](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%5Bmy) team id]/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppDefinition&$filter=teamsAppDefinition/teamsAppId eq '{cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41}'

it returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('a001122-2c62-4006-adaa-6d8112b660f3')/installedApp...())",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```

The same if use (GET):

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[my](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%5Bmy) team id]/installedApps/cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41

where I get:

"No app installation found with id 'cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41' for team '[my team id]'."

Clearly the app is not installed, so any ideas on why this suddenly started to happen as it has worked?

/Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in my call to check if the app is already installed where "{" and "}" around the id shall not be there.

So using the correct call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/[my team id]/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppDefinition&$filter=teamsAppDefinition/teamsAppId eq 'cd2d8695-bdc9-4d8e-9620-cc963ed81f41'
```

Returns if the app is installed or not and I can use the above call prior trying to install the app to ensure it is not installed.